# this program doesn't show the output

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Create a JavaScript Object</h2>
<p id="hi"></p>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var tst=[{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName"    :"Anna",
    "lastName"   :"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName"   :"Peter",
    "lastName"   :"Jones"
    }];

text[0].name=   "CCCC";alert(text);
document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML=text[0].name+" "+text[0].classs;

</script>
```

//this program does'nt show the output.What can i do?
i can create a java script object and access array fields by this object.

this program shows only the heading portion and not the array element

Comment: The `<script>` section should be within the `<html>` content...

Comment: The `<script>` section should be within the `<html>` content, but before the closing body tag `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you ,it's a subtle mistake. But I have just started to learn new things ,Only way to make way for things is to break them. I would highly appreciate if downvoters can remove their down votes and appreciate my learning efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Create a JavaScript Object</h2>
<p id="hi"></p>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var tst=[{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName"    :"Anna",
    "lastName"   :"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName"   :"Peter",
    "lastName"   :"Jones"
    }];

text[0].name=   "CCCC";alert(text);
document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML=text[0].name+" "+text[0].classs;

</script>
```

You must keep `<script></script>` within the `<html></html>` tag and the array you declared is  var tst=....; but you are doing

```
text[0].name=   "CCCC";alert(text);
    document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML=text[0].name+" "+text[0].classs;
```

focus what you are doing.Okay

Comment: Oh..that's a blunder.Actually I was parsing the jSON and settting the optput in text var ,forget to remove that.I am a novice here :) Thanks for all your help.